# ODBC Driver Error Querying External Table

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I've set up an external table in Azure SQL in order to execute an elastic query according to the docs here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview?view=azuresql

I can see the external table in Azure Data Studio, but when I select data I get the following error:

> Msg 46833, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> An error occurred while executing query on remote server: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name

Answer (score 1):

I get this error:

> Msg 46833, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> An error occurred while executing query on remote server:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name

Make sure your connection is proper if you connected to any other database, you would get

> Invalid object name

kind of error, because the object you want is not present in that database.

We reproduced same thing in our environment, and we can select data from external table.

Sample code:

create master key

```sql
CREATE MASTER  KEY;
```

Create scoped credentials

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasqurDb12
WITH IDENTITY = 'username', SECRET = 'password';
```

Create external data source

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElASqurDC12 WITH
(
    TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = 'servername.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'demo2',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasqurDb12,
);
```

Create external table

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Persons12 
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
) 
WITH 
(
    DATA_SOURCE = MyElASqurDC12,
    SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo',
    OBJECT_NAME = 'Persons'
);
```

Select from external table

```sql
SELECT *  
FROM Persons12;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, not sure what the issue is with my connection.  I'll try and find out

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what I was doing wrong is that while creating external table, I was changing the name of the table( to distinguish between the remote table and external table) without specifying the schema name and object name in WITH clause after data source name.

Hence, I was receiving this error of invalid object name i.e. trying to query a table name that does not exist in the original database!!

I tried to add schema name and object name along with data source name in WITH clause while creating the external table with a name different than original one; I was able to achieve the expected result from cross DB query